# mysql hamming distance between two phash

Tags: mysql, hamming-distance

I have a table A which has a column 'template_phash'. I store the phash generated from 400K images.

Now I take a random image and generate a phash from that image.

Now how do I query so that I can get the record from table A which hamming distance difference is less than a threshold value, say 20.

I have seen [Hamming distance on binary strings in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777070/hamming-distance-on-binary-strings-in-sql), but couldn't figure it out.

I think I figured out that I need to make a function to achieve this but how?

**Both of my phash are in BigInt eg: 7641692061273169067**

Please help me make the function so that I could query like

```
SELECT product_id, HAMMING_DISTANCE(phash1,  phash2) as hd 
FROM A 
WHERE hd < 20 ORDER BY hd ASC;
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I figured out that the hamming distance is just the count of different bits between the two hashes. First xor the two hashes then get the count of binary ones:

```
SELECT product_id, BIT_COUNT(phash1 ^ phash2) as hd from A ORDER BY hd ASC;
```