# How can I calculate the difference between two hashes in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, hash, bit-manipulation, hamming-distance, phash

I'm attempting to calculate the Hamming distance between an input hash and database-stored hashes. These are perceptual hashes, so the Hamming distance between them are important to me and tell me how similar two different images are (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing, http://jenssegers.com/61/perceptual-image-hashes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037578/). Hashes are 16 hexadecimal characters long, and look like this:

> b1d0c44a4eb5b5a9 
>   1f69f25228ed4a31 
>   751a0b19f0c2783f

My database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `hashes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` binary(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `hashes` (`id`, `hash`) VALUES
    (1, 0xb1d0c44a4eb5b5a9),
    (2, 0x1f69f25228ed4a31),
    (3, 0x751a0b19f0c2783f);
```

Now, I know I can query for a Hamming distance like so:

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(0xb1d0c44a4eb5b5a9 ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f)
```

Which will output 38, as expected. However, I can't seem to reference a column name for this comparison. The following does not work as expected.

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(hash ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f) FROM hashes
```

Does anyone know how I can calculate a Hamming distance like in my first `SELECT` query above using the columns in my database? I've tried a myriad of scenarios using `hex()`, `unhex()`, `conv()`, and `cast()` in different ways. This is in MySQL.

**Update** My query above appears to work as expected when running in MySQL v8 (thanks to @LukStorms for pointing this out). You can use my fiddle below and change the version in the top left. My question now is: how can I ensure the behavior works in all versions of MySQL?

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mpqsUpZ1sv2kmvRwJrK5xL/0

Comment: BIT_COUNT does not calculate hamming distance it just counts the bits which are set.

Comment: @RaymondNijland this is why I perform an XOR as well. XOR -> count set bets is essentially hamming distance if the hashes are binary. this works in my first select query

Comment: @AndrewMorton These are perceptual hashes, thus the Hamming is very important to me if I'm trying to query for duplicate/similar images. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing https://jenssegers.com/61/perceptual-image-hashes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037578/mysql-hamming-distance-between-two-phash

Comment: @AndrewMorton very interesting to me as well. I've updated my question

Comment: @LukStorms If they are equal, the expected Hamming distance is in fact zero (no difference). That said, not all the Hamming distances are correct

Comment: Interesting enough, this *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f46c845cc6c95c580fd1f43698bc007c)* doesn't seem to have a problem with it. A bug they fixed in MySql 8?

Comment: @LukStorms that is verrrryyy interesting. i wonder if it is a bug? the fiddle I posted to also allows you to switch it to mysql8, where it works as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to your choice of datatype which is a string type. Using a numeric datatype works in MySQL 5.7 as well as 8.0:

```
CREATE TABLE `hashes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` bigint unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `hashes` (`id`, `hash`) VALUES
    (1, 0xb1d0c44a4eb5b5a9),
    (2, 0x1f69f25228ed4a31),
    (3, 0x751a0b19f0c2783f);

SELECT id, HEX(hash), BIT_COUNT(hash ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f)
FROM hashes;
```

Output:

```
id  HEX(hash)           BIT_COUNT(hash ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f)
1   B1D0C44A4EB5B5A9    38
2   1F69F25228ED4A31    34
3   751A0B19F0C2783F    0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mpqsUpZ1sv2kmvRwJrK5xL/2)

The difference in treatment between MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 of using a string type can be seen with this query:

```
SELECT id, hash, HEX(hash), HEX(hash ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f)
FROM hashes;
```

MySQL 5.7:

```
id  hash                                                        HEX(hash)           HEX(hash ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f)
1   {"type":"Buffer","data":[177,208,196,74,78,181,181,169]}    B1D0C44A4EB5B5A9    751A0B19F0C2783F
2   {"type":"Buffer","data":[31,105,242,82,40,237,74,49]}       1F69F25228ED4A31    751A0B19F0C2783F
3   {"type":"Buffer","data":[117,26,11,25,240,194,120,63]}      751A0B19F0C2783F    751A0B19F0C2783F
```

MySQL 8.0

```
id  hash                                                        HEX(hash)           HEX(hash ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f)
1   {"type":"Buffer","data":[177,208,196,74,78,181,181,169]}    B1D0C44A4EB5B5A9    C4CACF53BE77CD96
2   {"type":"Buffer","data":[31,105,242,82,40,237,74,49]}       1F69F25228ED4A31    6A73F94BD82F320E
3   {"type":"Buffer","data":[117,26,11,25,240,194,120,63]}      751A0B19F0C2783F    0000000000000000
```

MySQL 8.0 is performing the XOR correctly, returning a variable, while MySQL 5.7 is returning the value being XOR'ed, indicating that it is treating the `BINARY` string as 0 in a numeric context.

Comment: interesting. why can't I store numbers & retrieve them as such from binary types? this works in mysql 8

Comment: @jeremy see my update. It shows that MySQL 5.7 is treating the string as 0 in a numeric context, where MySQL 8 is casting it to a number

Comment: hm... it looks like bigint is not large enough to store 'b1d0c44a4eb5b5a9', so i guess this was my miscalculation in wanting a binary(8) in the first place.

Comment: since the largest possible value is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, I think I should use a decimal(64,0)

Comment: @jeremy you need to use `bigint unsigned` as I did in my demo

Comment: I am, but for some reason it says `Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value` when I insert w/ `UPDATE`. see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mpqsUpZ1sv2kmvRwJrK5xL/4

Comment: You need to keep the value in hex format i.e. `UPDATE \`hashes\` SET \`hash\` = 0x1f69f25228ed4a31 WHERE id = 1;` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mpqsUpZ1sv2kmvRwJrK5xL/5

Comment: You could use `CONV` e.g. `UPDATE \`hashes\` SET \`hash\` = CONV('1f69f25228ed4a31', 16, 10) WHERE id = 1;` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mpqsUpZ1sv2kmvRwJrK5xL/7

Comment: No worries. All part of the service :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a number, so it can't used for mathematic calculations:

```
`hash` binary(8) NOT NULL
```

Use bigint instead:

```
`hash` bigint unsigned NOT NULL
```

Comment: interesting. why can't I store numbers & retrieve them as such from binary types? this works in mysql 8

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, HEX(hash), CAST(CONV(HEX(hash),16,10) AS UNSIGNED), BIT_COUNT(CAST(CONV(HEX(hash),16,10) AS UNSIGNED) ^ 0x751a0b19f0c2783f) FROM hashes;
```