# T-SQL Hamming distance function capable of decimal / string / UInt64

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, user-defined-functions, hamming-distance

I need to convert this c# function to a T-SQL UDF

I need to get all the rows from a database that have a humming distance smaller than x
This function is just part of the solution.

The csharp function return 40 for these 2 hashes while the t-sql function returns 52

14714557628763197901

15383788748848265778

```
public static ulong csharp_hamming_distance(ulong hash1, ulong hash2)
{
ulong x = hash1 ^ hash2;
const ulong m1 = 0x5555555555555555UL;
const ulong m2 = 0x3333333333333333UL;
const ulong h01 = 0x0101010101010101UL;
ulong m4 = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fUL;
x -= (x >> 1) & m1;
x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2);
x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m4;
return (x * h01) >> 56;
}
```

I have sample but it is does not give me the same results.

```
create function HammingDistance1(@value1 char(8000), @value2 char(8000))
returns int
as
begin
    declare @distance int
    declare @i int
    declare @len int

    select @distance = 0,
           @i =1,
           @len = case when len(@value1) > len(@value2)
                       then len(@value1)
                       else len(@value2) end

    if (@value1 is null) or (@value2 is null)
        return null

    while (@i <= @len)
        select @distance = @distance +
                           case 
                           when substring(@value1,@i,1) = substring(@value2,@i,1)
                                then 0
                           when substring(@value1,@i,1) < substring(@value2,@i,1)
                                then  CAST(substring(@value2,@i,1) as smallint) -  CAST(substring(@value1,@i,1) as smallint)
                           when substring(@value1,@i,1) > substring(@value2,@i,1)
                                then  CAST(substring(@value1,@i,1) as smallint) - CAST(substring(@value2,@i,1) as smallint)
                          else 1 end,
               @i = @i +1
    return @distance
end
```

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Why not just do it as a CLR UDF, presumably passing in the value as `long` (rather than `ulong`) and using -3732186444946353715 and -3062955324861285838 as the inputs?

Comment: Side note: string hamming and binary hamming are different; by my calculations, the string hamming between those two values *as strings* is 18... how do you get 52?

Comment: Thank you !! If I did not have to run a query like this 

SELECT Id FROM InstagramPhoto 
WHERE
dbo.HamDist(
convert(varchar,convert(decimal(32,0),phash)),
convert(varchar,convert(decimal(32,0),15383788748848265778)))  <15 

where the 1 field is populated from the database and I would have considered it. 
But I do not know how to cast 14714557628763197901 to the value -3732186444946353715 in a query like this.

or to convert it to 4 bigints to use in this query
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777070/hamming-distance-on-binary-strings-in-sql

Comment: `14714557628763197901` doesn't fit in a `bigint`; `-3732186444946353715` is just the signed (rather than unsigned) interpretation of the same bit pattern (note: negative because the MSB is set).

Answer (score 1):

In hamming calculations, integers are treated as bits. The hamming distance is the number of bit differences, which can be calculated as the number of non-zero bits in the xor of the two values. For the two integers you provide, the bitwise hamming distance is indeed 40.

```
14714557628763197901=
   1100110000110100100111000011001111001001011100011101000111001101

15383788748848265778=
   1101010101111110001100100101110000111010110000000111101000110010

^= 0001100101001010101011100110111111110011101100011010101111111111
```

which is 40 non-zero bits. The C# shown is just a fancy way of counting them.

This is not the case with strings. In the TSQL you are performing string hamming, which is *classically* just the number of positions at which the characters are different. Performing a *classic* hamming distance on those two values *as strings* gives:

```
"14714557628763197901"
"15383788748848265778"
 01111111110111111111 = 18
```

Youre example TSQL code is performing a modified hamming calculation; to get the classic hamming distance, just remove the last two `when` clauses.

To perform a *binary* hamming distance on `bigint` in TSQL will be very hard, because TSQL does not support bitwise operations on bigint. You could, however, perform the calculation on the left and right halves separately using integer arithmetic, and then add them. The only tricky part is that damned MSB and the impact on shifting.

Performing hamming distance on a decimal is not well-defined. You would need to be more specific about what you think that means.